# Why can't I setText this jTextField?

Tags: java, string, swing, jtextfield, settext

So I have been writting this code, but for 2 days I haven't been able to figure out the problem. 
This is the fragment of the code where the problem is:

```
public void updatee(String gatavs){
    lauks.setText(gatavs);
    System.out.println(gatavs+"?!");
}
public void setup(int garums, String vards){

    labul.setText(vards);
    int i=1;
    String a="-";
    while(i<=garums){
        lauks.setText(a);
        a=a+"-";
        i++;
    }
}
```

This is in a JFrame class. At the start I call the method *setup* from another class and it sets the text in *lauks* textfield just fine, but later when i call the method *updatee* it doesn't settext *lauks* to the other string. I even put the println so i could check if it has the string *gatavs*, and it printed to the console just fine. What could be the problem here?

EDIT:Here is the full JFrame class:

```
package oliverakaratavas;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    int startif = 0;
    OliveraKaratavas par = new OliveraKaratavas();

    public MyFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        lauks = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        a = new javax.swing.JButton();
        b = new javax.swing.JButton();
        c = new javax.swing.JButton();
        d = new javax.swing.JButton();
        e = new javax.swing.JButton();
        f = new javax.swing.JButton();
        g = new javax.swing.JButton();
        h = new javax.swing.JButton();
        i = new javax.swing.JButton();
        j = new javax.swing.JButton();
        k = new javax.swing.JButton();
        l = new javax.swing.JButton();
        m = new javax.swing.JButton();
        n = new javax.swing.JButton();
        o = new javax.swing.JButton();
        p = new javax.swing.JButton();
        r = new javax.swing.JButton();
        s = new javax.swing.JButton();
        t = new javax.swing.JButton();
        u = new javax.swing.JButton();
        v = new javax.swing.JButton();
        z = new javax.swing.JButton();
        labul = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        jLabel2.setText("jLabel2");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Karatavas");

        lauks.setEditable(false);
        lauks.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        lauks.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);

        a.setText("A");
        a.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                aActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        b.setText("B");
        b.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                bActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        c.setText("C");
        c.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                cActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        d.setText("D");
        d.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                dActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        e.setText("E");
        e.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                eActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        f.setText("F");
        f.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                fActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        g.setText("G");
        g.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                gActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        h.setText("H");
        h.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                hActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        i.setText("I");
        i.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                iActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        j.setText("J");
        j.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        k.setText("K");
        k.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                kActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        l.setText("L");
        l.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                lActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        m.setText("M");
        m.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                mActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        n.setText("N");
        n.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                nActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        o.setText("O");
        o.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                oActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        p.setText("P");
        p.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                pActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        r.setText("R");
        r.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                rActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        s.setText("S");
        s.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                sActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        t.setText("T");
        t.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                tActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        u.setText("U");
        u.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                uActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        v.setText("V");
        v.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                vActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        z.setText("Z");
        z.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                zActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(
                layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addGroup(
                                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                        .addComponent(i, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE).addComponent(a))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(
                                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addGroup(
                                                layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                        .addGroup(
                                                                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                                                        .addGroup(
                                                                                layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                                        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                                        .addGap(127, 127, 127))
                                                                        .addGroup(
                                                                                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                                                        .addGroup(
                                                                                                layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                                                        .addComponent(j, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25,
                                                                                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                                                                        .addComponent(k, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25,
                                                                                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                                                                        .addComponent(l, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25,
                                                                                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                                                                        .addComponent(m)
                                                                                                        .addGap(4, 4, 4)
                                                                                                        .addComponent(n, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25,
                                                                                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                                                                        .addComponent(o, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25,
                                                                                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                                                                        .addComponent(p, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25,
                                                                                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                                                                        .addGroup(
                                                                                                layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                                                        .addGroup(
                                                                                                                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                                                                                                        .addGroup(
                                                                                                                                layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                                                                                        .addComponent(b, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25,
                                                                                                                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                                                                                        .addPreferredGap(
                                                                                                                                                javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                                                                                                        .addComponent(c, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25,
                                                                                                                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                                                                                        .addPreferredGap(
                                                                                                                                                javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                                                                                                        .addComponent(d, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25,
                                                                                                                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                                                                                        .addPreferredGap(
                                                                                                                                                javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                                                                                                        .addComponent(e, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25,
                                                                                                                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                                                                                        .addPreferredGap(
                                                                                                                                                javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                                                                                                        .addComponent(f, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25,
                                                                                                                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                                                                                        .addPreferredGap(
                                                                                                                                                javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                                                                                                        .addComponent(g, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25,
                                                                                                                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                                                                                                        .addComponent(lauks))
                                                                                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                                                                        .addComponent(h, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25,
                                                                                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))).addContainerGap())
                                        .addGroup(
                                                layout.createSequentialGroup().addComponent(r, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                        .addComponent(s, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                        .addComponent(t, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                        .addComponent(u, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                        .addComponent(v, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                        .addComponent(z, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                                        .addComponent(labul, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))));

        layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, new java.awt.Component[] { a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, r, s, t, u, v, z });

        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(
                layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(lauks, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(
                                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                        .addComponent(a, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 33, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addComponent(b, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addComponent(c, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addComponent(d, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addComponent(e, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addComponent(f, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addComponent(g, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addComponent(h, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(
                                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                        .addGroup(
                                                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                                        .addComponent(i, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                        .addComponent(j, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                        .addComponent(k, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                        .addComponent(l, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                        .addComponent(n, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                        .addComponent(o, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                        .addComponent(p, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                        .addComponent(m, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGroup(
                                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                        .addComponent(r, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addComponent(s, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addComponent(t, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addComponent(u, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addComponent(v, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addComponent(z, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(labul, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)));

        layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.VERTICAL, new java.awt.Component[] { a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, n, o, p, r, s, t, u, v, z });

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void tActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String word = labul.getText();
        String gatavs = lauks.getText();
        char b = 'T';
        par.parbaud1(b, word, gatavs);
    }

    private void uActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String word = labul.getText();
        String gatavs = lauks.getText();
        char b = 'U';
        par.parbaud1(b, word, gatavs);
    }

    private void vActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String word = labul.getText();
        String gatavs = lauks.getText();
        char b = 'V';
        par.parbaud1(b, word, gatavs);
    }

    private void zActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String word = labul.getText();
        String gatavs = lauks.getText();
        char b = 'Z';
        par.parbaud1(b, word, gatavs);
    }

    private void aActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String word = labul.getText();
        String gatavs = lauks.getText();
        char b = 'A';
        par.parbaud1(b, word, gatavs);
    }

    private void bActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String word = labul.getText();
        String gatavs = lauks.getText();
        char b = 'B';
        par.parbaud1(b, word, gatavs);
    }

    private void cActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String word = labul.getText();
        String gatavs = lauks.getText();
        char b = 'C';
        par.parbaud1(b, word, gatavs);
    }

    private void dActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String word = labul.getText();
        String gatavs = lauks.getText();
        char b = 'D';
        par.parbaud1(b, word, gatavs);
    }

    private void eActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String word = labul.getText();
        String gatavs = lauks.getText();
        char b = 'E';
        par.parbaud1(b, word, gatavs);
    }

    private void fActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String word = labul.getText();
        String gatavs = lauks.getText();
        char b = 'F';
        par.parbaud1(b, word, gatavs);
    }

    private void gActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String word = labul.getText();
        String gatavs = lauks.getText();
        char b = 'G';
        par.parbaud1(b, word, gatavs);
    }

    private void hActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String word = labul.getText();
        String gatavs = lauks.getText();
        char b = 'H';
        par.parbaud1(b, word, gatavs);
    }

    private void iActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String word = labul.getText();
        String gatavs = lauks.getText();
        char b = 'I';
        par.parbaud1(b, word, gatavs);
    }

    private void jActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String word = labul.getText();
        String gatavs = lauks.getText();
        char b = 'J';
        par.parbaud1(b, word, gatavs);
    }

    private void kActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String word = labul.getText();
        String gatavs = lauks.getText();
        char b = 'K';
        par.parbaud1(b, word, gatavs);
    }

    private void lActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String word = labul.getText();
        String gatavs = lauks.getText();
        char b = 'L';
        par.parbaud1(b, word, gatavs);
    }

    private void mActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String word = labul.getText();
        String gatavs = lauks.getText();
        char b = 'M';
        par.parbaud1(b, word, gatavs);
    }

    private void nActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String word = labul.getText();
        String gatavs = lauks.getText();
        char b = 'N';
        par.parbaud1(b, word, gatavs);
    }

    private void oActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String word = labul.getText();
        String gatavs = lauks.getText();
        char b = 'O';
        par.parbaud1(b, word, gatavs);
    }

    private void pActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String word = labul.getText();
        String gatavs = lauks.getText();
        char b = 'P';
        par.parbaud1(b, word, gatavs);
    }

    private void rActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String word = labul.getText();
        String gatavs = lauks.getText();
        char b = 'R';
        par.parbaud1(b, word, gatavs);
    }

    private void sActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String word = labul.getText();
        String gatavs = lauks.getText();
        char b = 'S';
        par.parbaud1(b, word, gatavs);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new JFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public void updatee(String gatavs) {
        lauks.setText(gatavs);
        System.out.println(gatavs + "?!");
    }

    public void setup(int garums, String vards) {
        labul.setText(vards);
        int i = 1;
        String a = "-";
        while (i <= garums) {
            lauks.setText(a);
            a = a + "-";
            i++;
        }
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton a;
    private javax.swing.JButton b;
    private javax.swing.JButton c;
    private javax.swing.JButton d;
    private javax.swing.JButton e;
    private javax.swing.JButton f;
    private javax.swing.JButton g;
    private javax.swing.JButton h;
    private javax.swing.JButton i;
    private javax.swing.JButton j;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JButton k;
    private javax.swing.JButton l;
    private javax.swing.JLabel labul;
    private javax.swing.JTextField lauks;
    private javax.swing.JButton m;
    private javax.swing.JButton n;
    private javax.swing.JButton o;
    private javax.swing.JButton p;
    private javax.swing.JButton r;
    private javax.swing.JButton s;
    private javax.swing.JButton t;
    private javax.swing.JButton u;
    private javax.swing.JButton v;
    private javax.swing.JButton z;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

And here is the class with the *main* method that calls the method *updatee*:

```
package oliverakaratavas;

public class OliveraKaratavas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vards v = new Vards();
        v.nofaila();
    }

    public void parbaud1(char b, String word, String gatavs) {
        int k = 0;
        MyFrame j = new MyFrame();
        while (k < word.length()) {
            char ch = word.charAt(k);
            if (ch == b) {
                gatavs = gatavs.substring(0, k) + ch + gatavs.substring(k + 1);
            }
            k++;
        }
        j.updatee(gatavs);
        System.out.println(gatavs);

    }
}
```

Tell me if you need anything else!

FINAL EDIT: The problem was answered, thanks to tmarven!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  Note though that `setText(..)` does not ***append*** information to a text field, but replaces the current text, so calling `setText(..)` in a loop seems to be a mistake.

Comment: can you show the declaration of `JTextField lauks;`?

Comment: The method _setup_ isn't the problem here, it's the method _updatee_.

Comment: @Ubica It's the standart generated NetBeans declaration of JTextField.

Comment: You should definitely post a working version of that JFrame... 'cause it's not clear what has gone wrong and what this code actually tries to accomplish.

Comment: How are you calling the `updatee()` method? That should should be the key I think...

Comment: *"The method setup isn't the problem here, it's the method updatee."*  That's why you should ***post an MCVE.***  Which to quote one user results in (WTE) *"..less confusion and better answers"*.  Am voting to close for lack of an MCVE.

Comment: You may have one instance of `lauks` that shadows another; please edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: You have a main method inside your JFrame class and you shouldn't have 2 main methods. Also what is `Vards` class?

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of design issues and you should consider starting your project from scratch. I am not an expert in Swing, but you might wanna consider something like this:

Start with a main class that will be used only for starting up your program and making some ground level configurations:

```
public class WPMAIN {

    // Entry point of your program (should be one and only)
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Creation of the frame and setting it visible
        WPFrame frame = new WPFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Then in the JFrame, try to minimize redundant code. If you have tons of buttons, that do the same thing, but just a little bit differently, make a method that contains all the code that remains the same:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class WPFrame extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JButton A;
    private JButton B;

    public WPFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        A = new JButton("A");
        setupButton(A);
        B = new JButton("B");
        setupButton(B);

        GroupLayout gl_contentPane = new GroupLayout(contentPane);
        gl_contentPane.setHorizontalGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(
                gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup().addComponent(A, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE).addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(B, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE).addContainerGap(237, Short.MAX_VALUE)));
        gl_contentPane.setVerticalGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(
                gl_contentPane
                        .createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(
                                gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE).addComponent(A, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addComponent(B, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)).addContainerGap(227, Short.MAX_VALUE)));
        contentPane.setLayout(gl_contentPane);
    }

    public void setupButton(final JButton init) {
        init.setMargin(new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2));
        init.setSize(25, 25);
        init.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(25, 25));
        init.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(25, 25));
        init.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(25, 25));
        init.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));

        // Action listener that is separate for each button you create,
        // but like this you control all the buttons' actions at once
        init.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(init.getText());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(contentPane, "You pressed " + init.getText());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Note that this is only a suggestion, I don't claim this is the right way to do it, or the best way to do it... Just that it will give you more control with the code you are writing. You can take these classes, and run them to see how it works. It's reasonably simple and maybe you can try to build on it.

Comment: *"..but you might wanna consider.."*  You might want to consider avoiding slang words like 'wanna' in order to help those people for whom English is a second language.  See also [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)  Besides that 1) Use `pack()` instead of `setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);` 2) Don't extend `JFrame` when we only need an instance. 3) I prefer `JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` --  Good call on building the GUI in a panel - plus one for that.

Comment: It's just an example, not "the best way to do it". All the GUI parameters are Eclipse generated. I just made an example of how he/she can reuse code for multiple buttons, which are causing the mess in his/her code.

Comment: Are you stating that Eclipse either prompted you to set the sizes of buttons/bounds of the frame or did that automatically?  I very much doubt that, but if it did it is a piece of crap that shouldn't be used for GUIs - since it is encouraging bad practices (that make for fragile UIs).

Comment: Well it's WindowBuilder/Swing Designer/JFrame that does some of those things. I just clicked on some random properties as an example. This is by default how the code looks when it's generated: https://gist.github.com/Ubica/8f4f0f40585ba5e6f0f0

Answer (score 0):

Looking into your source code, it seems like you have a lot of issues mixed together which does not only concern the `setup()` method (note that I can't even see a call to this method in the main OP):

- The major one for me is your `parbaud1` signature and body, where you are creating an instance of `JFrame` (your own frame implementation) and calling the `parbaud1` method on that instance object:

  ```
  JFrame j = new JFrame();
  //...
  jFrame.updatee(gatavs);
  ```

This will almost result on a new object created each time one of you action listeners delegate the event handling logic to this method having no effective result on your main frame since your code is applied on a different object from you visual one.

The soltution would then be to change the method signature to hold a `JFrame` instance, and pass the current JFrame instance in each call in your action listener logic:

```
public void parbaud1(JFrame jFrame, char b, String word, String gatavs)
{
  int k = 0;
  //    JFrame j = new JFrame();
  while (k < word.length())
  {
    char ch = word.charAt(k);
    if (ch == b)
    {
      gatavs = gatavs.substring(0, k) + ch + gatavs.substring(k + 1);
    }
    k++;
  }
  jFrame.updatee(gatavs); // Update the parmaeter argument and don't create a new one
  System.out.println(gatavs);
}
```

Then calling it as follows:

```
private void aActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{
  String word = labul.getText();
  String gatavs = lauks.getText();
  char b = 'A';
  par.parbaud1(this, b, word, gatavs); // Use the current JFrame instance
}
```

- The second issue may be that no text is appended to the `gatavs` object since the main condition `k < word.length()` is never reached, **why?**.

Simply said because following the method chaining the `word` will reference the `labul` object which is never filled with text (`word.lenght()` will be always **0**), so you may need to initialize that label with some text following your needs.

Fixing both upper listing would help wordarounding the updatee method issue, but you still will fall into others reading your code such as `StringOutOBoundException`s, e.g:

```
gatavs = gatavs.substring(0, k) + ch + gatavs.substring(k + 1); // If the first character is matched gatavs.substring(k+1) will fail because you gatavs String which value come from `lauks` is already empty because the text field is not even editable.
```

[Here](https://github.com/tmarwen/stackoverflow-showcase/tree/master/27885785) you can a working copy of your code.